# Как сохранить файл в папку с программой?

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
public void writeToFile(String path, String fileName, ArrayList<String> write_text) {
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path,fileName));
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
    osw.write(str4rec);
    osw.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) { Log.d("MyLog","Exception: " + t.toString()); }
}
```

Но мне надо указать, чтобы файл записался в папку с программой.

Раньше использовал Context

```
 OutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод конеткста `getDir(String name, int mode);` Например:

```
File file = context.getDir(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

В этом случае `file` будет находится в приватном каталоге вашего приложения.